# Filtering ServiceM8 JSON-API

Tags: servicem8

I am trying to get a list of all job numbers that are scheduled for todays date from ServiceM8. I am using the "Job Activity" API and tying to filter it by the "start_date" field which is formatted like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss". I need to filter it to get all jobs on calendar for today only regardless of time stamp. The full json has 10s of thousands of entries and downloading and filter after is to slow. Here are some examples of what I have tried already.

`"JobActivity.json?%24filter=start_date%20eq%20%222023-12-15%22"` - returns nothing.

`"JobActivity.json?%24filter=start_date%20eq%20%222023-12-15 00:00:00%22"` - "An error occurred"

And a hundred other with ranging responses from 400, 500, 200-but returning all records. etc.

Can someone please help me with the formatting?